# How to generate json data for dynamic rows in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I want to generate Json data for dynamic rows in the table in angularjs i used ng-model for each input tag.

```
  <form name="userForm3" ng-submit="submit()">
   <tr ng-repeat="item in invoice.items">
    <td><select   ng-options="item as item.name for item in invoice.items[0].loyality " name="item.loyality" ng-model=" form3.loyality" required></select></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="item.value" ng-model="form3.value" required style="width:100px"></td>
       <td><select   ng-options="item as item.name for item in invoice.items[0].period " name="item.period" ng-model= " form3.period" required ></select></td>
     <td><a href ng-click="removeItem($index)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a></td>
    <td  ng-if=" form3.loyality || form3.value || form3.period " ><div id="c6">  <img   ng-src="images/Assets/WIP.png" /></div></td>
    </tr>
```

my angular code is

```
 var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', ['ngFlag']);
 $scope.invoice = {
    items: [{
         loyality: [{name:'points'},{name:'credits'}],
         value:0,
    period: [{name:'activity1'},{name:'activity2'}]
        }],
        items1:[{currency: [{name:'point'},{name:'credit'}],   value1:0   }]

};
  $scope.submit = function() {
  var data3=$scope.form3;
  console.log(data3);
    }

});
```

Comment: First, don't define two items variables referencing different things. Second, the inputs of each row should be bound to a different object. Something like `ng-model="item.enteredLoyalty"`

Comment: @JB,i didn't get you.

Comment: Your ng-repeat uses `item` for the current invoice element. Then right after, the ng-options uses `item` for the current loyalty element. This is confusi,ng. Choose better, distinct names. Second: all your loyalty inputs (for example) are bound to a unique variable `form3.loyality`. That can't work. You can't use a single variable to hold the value of many inputs.

Comment: this row is dynamic row so i have to keep ng-repeat as same i dont want to change it